# Was construction work involving hydraulic cements in ancient Rome restricted to the summer season?

Tags: roman-empire, classical-antiquity, building

Are Italian winter temperatures reliably warm enough for processing of opus caementicium ?

Was building activity seasonal for other reasons?

Comment: Since freezing is not particularly good for concrete and similar materials when solidifies, neither excessive rain, building is often seasonal activity even now in Europe.